# How can I iterate through a hash created with Rails' Hash#to_xml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, hash, iteration

I'm working with thetvdb.com API to get episode listings for a show. In general, the XML format is something like:

```
<Data>
<Series>...</Series>
<Episode><EpisodeName>Foo</EpisodeName><EpisodeNumber>1</EpisodeNumber></Episode>
<Episode><EpisodeName>Bar</EpisodeName><EpisodeNumber>2</EpisodeNumber></Episode>
</Data>
```

What I do is to parse the XML using `Hash.from_xml` and then process the data. To iterate through the episodes, I do something like:

```
hash_data['Data']['Episode'].each do ...
```

This works great if there are multiple episodes. But if there's only one episode, the `each` method actually iterates through the hash entries for that *single particular episode*, rather than just running the `each` method once. That breaks all of my code following it.

I tried:

```
hash_data['Data']['Episode'].to_a.each do ...
```

with the same results. There must be a "right" way to do this?

**UPDATE:** I thought this question was fairly clear, but it appears people are confused by it. To clarify, I'm really trying to just iterate through the episodes and look at the contents. The data is initially received as XML, so in order to examine it in Ruby, I convert it to a hash using `Hash.from_xml(xml_response)`.

In terms of "expected behaviour", take this example:

```
hash_data['Data']['Episode'].each do |e| { puts e['EpisodeNumber'] }
```

I would expect that given this initial data:

```
<Data>
<Series>...</Series>
<Episode><EpisodeName>Foo</EpisodeName><EpisodeNumber>1</EpisodeNumber></Episode>
<Episode><EpisodeName>Bar</EpisodeName><EpisodeNumber>2</EpisodeNumber></Episode>
</Data>
```

The output would be:

```
1
2
```

That works. However, if I'm given input like this:

```
<Data>
<Series>...</Series>
<Episode><EpisodeName>Foo</EpisodeName><EpisodeNumber>1</EpisodeNumber></Episode>
</Data>
```

I get a crash, because `e['EpisodeNumber']` is not valid. It's not valid because in the case of only one episode, the `each` actually iterates through *each key of the Hash* (so the first value coming into the `each` block is a key-value pair of EpisodeName) instead of being an *array of Hashes* as it was when there was more than one element.

In other words, when there are multiple episodes, `hash_data['Data']['Episode']` is an `Array` of `Hash` types. When there is only one episode, it's just a `Hash`. My code would work properly if, when there was one episode, it was *still* an `Array`, but with only one item in it. But that's not the case. How can I deal with this properly?

I hope that clears it up?

**UPDATE 2**: It's been requested that I post `Hash#inspect` for the returned data. Here it is for a show with a single episode:

```
{"Data"=>{"Series"=>{"id"=>"263752", "Actors"=>"||", "Airs_DayOfWeek"=>"Thursday", "Airs_Time"=>"10pm", "ContentRating"=>nil, "FirstAired"=>"2013-01-17", "Genre"=>"|Game Show|Reality|", "IMDB_ID"=>"tt2401129", "Language"=>"en", "Network"=>"TBS Superstation", "NetworkID"=>nil, "Overview"=>"Hosted by Robert Carradine and Curtis Armstrong, King of the Nerds is the ultimate nerd-off. The series will follow eleven fierce competitors from across the nerd spectrum as they set out to win $100,000 and be crowned the greatest nerd of them all.\n\nKing of the Nerds will take the glory of geekdom to a whole new level as the eleven competitors live together in \"Nerdvana.\" Each week, they must face challenges that will test their intellect, ingenuity, skills and pop culture prowess. In each episode, the nerds will first compete as teams and then as individuals, facing challenges that range from live gaming to a dance-off to life-sized chess. One competitor will be eliminated each week until one nerd stands alone as the ultimate champion off all things nerdy.", "Rating"=>nil, "RatingCount"=>"0", "Runtime"=>"60", "SeriesID"=>nil, "SeriesName"=>"King of the Nerds", "Status"=>"Continuing", "added"=>"2012-10-31 21:53:29", "addedBy"=>"348252", "banner"=>"graphical/263752-g2.jpg", "fanart"=>"fanart/original/263752-1.jpg", "lastupdated"=>"1357501598", "poster"=>nil, "zap2it_id"=>nil}, "Episode"=>{"id"=>"4428487", "Combined_episodenumber"=>"1", "Combined_season"=>"1", "DVD_chapter"=>nil, "DVD_discid"=>nil, "DVD_episodenumber"=>nil, "DVD_season"=>nil, "Director"=>nil, "EpImgFlag"=>nil, "EpisodeName"=>"Welcome to the Nerdvana", "EpisodeNumber"=>"1", "FirstAired"=>"2013-01-17", "GuestStars"=>nil, "IMDB_ID"=>nil, "Language"=>"en", "Overview"=>nil, "ProductionCode"=>nil, "Rating"=>nil, "RatingCount"=>"0", "SeasonNumber"=>"1", "Writer"=>nil, "absolute_number"=>nil, "filename"=>nil, "lastupdated"=>"1357501766", "seasonid"=>"504427", "seriesid"=>"263752"}}}
```

Notice that `Episode` is a `Hash` type.

Here it is for a show with more than one episode:

```
{"Data"=>{"Series"=>{"id"=>"220441", "Actors"=>"||", "Airs_DayOfWeek"=>"Saturday", "Airs_Time"=>"8:30PM", "ContentRating"=>"TV-PG", "FirstAired"=>"2010-12-25", "Genre"=>"|Children|Drama|", "IMDB_ID"=>"tt1765510", "Language"=>"en", "Network"=>"The Hub", "NetworkID"=>nil, "Overview"=>nil, "Rating"=>"7.0", "RatingCount"=>"1", "Runtime"=>"30", "SeriesID"=>nil, "SeriesName"=>"R L Stine's The Haunting Hour", "Status"=>"Continuing", "added"=>"2011-01-10 15:59:43", "addedBy"=>"66501", "banner"=>"graphical/220441-g.jpg", "fanart"=>"fanart/original/220441-1.jpg", "lastupdated"=>"1354439519", "poster"=>"posters/220441-1.jpg", "zap2it_id"=>nil}, "Episode"=>[{"id"=>"3453441", "Combined_episodenumber"=>"1", "Combined_season"=>"1", "DVD_chapter"=>nil, "DVD_discid"=>nil, "DVD_episodenumber"=>nil, "DVD_season"=>nil, "Director"=>nil, "EpImgFlag"=>"2", "EpisodeName"=>"Really You (Part 1)", "EpisodeNumber"=>"1", "FirstAired"=>"2010-10-29", "GuestStars"=>"|Bailee Madison|Connor Price|", "IMDB_ID"=>nil, "Language"=>"en", "Overview"=>"A girl named Lilly (Bailee Madison) is given her very own life-sized \"Really You\" doll which is named Lilly D.; because she is good at manipulating her dad. Lilly remains a spoiled brat, bragging about Lilly D, even going as far as ripping the leg off a friends doll, after the friend informs Lilly that \"Lilly D hates Lilly\". Soon after, strange events begin to occur which Lilly's mother accuses Lilly of doing; despite how Lilly maintains she is innocent, and that Lilly D is alive.", "ProductionCode"=>nil, "Rating"=>"8.0", "RatingCount"=>"1", "SeasonNumber"=>"1", "Writer"=>nil, "absolute_number"=>nil, "filename"=>"episodes/220441/3453441.jpg", "lastupdated"=>"1350772755", "seasonid"=>"393441", "seriesid"=>"220441"}, ...
```

Notice `Episode` is now an `Array` of `Hash` types.

Comment: Please include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Please post `hash_data.inspect` so we understand the structure of your hash data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Rails' `Array#wrap` method would solve your problem.  I believe this should work:

```
Array.wrap(hash_data['Data']['Episode']).each do ...
```

Documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/wrap/class).

Answer (score 1):

#### Use Hash Key/Value Methods

Rather than [Enumerator#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-each), you probably want to use [Hash#each_key](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-each_key), [Hash#each_value](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-each_value), or [Hash#each_pair](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-each_pair) to iterate through your hash.

Comment: I thought I had it figured out, but I actually just fixed it for single episodes and broke it for multiple ones. I added a big update that I hope clears up the confusion.